# How does one use the store parameter of function fields?

Tags: python, openerp-7

I've tried reading [the docs](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_02.html#store-parameter), but it's a bit confusing.

Also, does `store` work with any other field types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer the second question first:  The `related` and `sparse` fields are both subclasses of `function` so `store` *may/should* work with them, but I have not tried.

---

The idea behind the `store` parameter is to tell OpenERP if it is okay to remember and save the results of calling the function in order to avoid calling it again.

For how it works, let's look at the following example:

```
    'order_status': fields.function(
        _order_status,
        type='char',
        method=True,
        store= . . . ,
        string='Order Status',
        ),
```

By default, `store` is `False` -- meaning that the function field will be evaluated everytime the record is requested.

There are, however, two other possible values -- `True`, or a `dict` of `tuple`s.

```
        store=True,
```

`True` is easy to understand, and simply means that the value will be calculated once, stored, and then recalculated every time that record changes.

```
        store={
            'model.table': (function, ['field1', 'field2', ...], priority),
            'another_model.table': (some_func, [], priority),
            },
```

The `dict` of `tuple`s is both somewhat complicated as well as very powerful.  With it we can tell OpenERP *when* we want the field recalculated.

The keys are tables, such as `res.partner` or `product.product`; the first item in the three item tuple is the function to call, the second items is a list of fields in the key table to monitor, and the last item is the priority, or sequence, to process the functions in if there are more than one<sup>1</sup>.

An example is in order:

```
        store={
            'product.product': (_get_product_dependent_ids, ['name','price'], 20),
            'res.partner': (_get_partner_dependent_ids, ['login'], 10),
            },
```

Working backwards, the priorities (last item of each tuple) tells us that the `res.partner` tuple will run first, as it has a lower priority.

The middle item is the list of fields to monitor:  for `res.partner` OpenERP will monitor the `login` field, and any time the `login` field is changed OpenERP will call `_get_partner_dependent_ids`; likewise, anytime the `name` or `price` fields for a `product.product` record is changed, OpenERP will call `_get_product_dependent_ids`<sup>2</sup>.

The first item in the tuple is the function to call, and it is the tricky part.  The signature of this function is:

```
def _get_ids(key_table, cr, uid, ids_of_changed_records, context=None):
```

**Note that `key_table` is NOT `self`!**  Even though this function is probably a method in your dependent class (for example, `custom.table1`), the first parameter is not that table, but is the table listed as the key in the store dictionary -- `product.product` or `res.partner` in our example<sup>3</sup>.

What is this function supposed to do?  It is supposed to return a list of all the record ids in your custom table that need to have that field recalculated.

Here's my function field:

```
    'order_status': fields.function(
        _order_status,
        type='char',
        method=True,
        store={
            'fnx.pd.order': (_get_schedule_ids_for_order, ['state'], 20),
            },
```

and my store function:

```
def _get_schedule_ids_for_order(fnx_pd_order, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if not isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        [ids] = ids
    return [s.id for s in fnx_pd_order.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context).schedule_ids]
```

What the field definition tells us is that any time the `state` field is changed on a record in `fnx.pd.order`, `_get_schedule_ids_for_order` will be called with the ids of the records in `fnx.pd.order` that had their `state` field changed.

`_get_schedule_ids_for_order` looks up the changed record, gets the ids of the linked schedule records, and returns them.

---

Footnotes:

1. The `priority` field sorts every `_get_ids()` function for every field in the table, not just the `_get_ids()` for an individual function.  This is very useful when one function field depends on another.
2. If the field list is empty, then any modification to any field will cause the function to be called.
3. If you need access to your own table inside the function you can do

   ```
   self = key_table.pool.get('my_module_name_here.my_table_name_here')
   ```