# How to using fields.function?

Tags: python, odoo

Can you help me understand the functions and working of Field.function through this code?

```
'progress': fields.function(_hours_get, string='Working Time Progress (%)', multi='hours', group_operator="avg", help="If the task has a progress of 99.99% you should close the task if it's finished or reevaluate the time",
                store = {
                    'project.task': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['work_ids', 'remaining_hours', 'planned_hours', 'state', 'stage_id'], 10),
                    'project.task.work': (_get_task, ['hours'], 10),
                }),
```

I needed to understand them.
Hope the response.
Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I ll give you a simple exemple to understand Field.function.

Exemple:

```
    def _check_bool(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
       res={}
       for req in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
          if req.bool:
                res[req.id] = True
          else:
                res[req.id] = False
       return res

    _columns = {
       'bool' : fields.boolean(),
       'check_bool': fields.function(_check_bool, type="boolean", obj="generic.request", method=True),
    }
```

The **_check_bool** function checks if the **field 'bool'** is True of False and makes the same for **field 'check_bool'** the code is easy to undersant , if you have a question im here to help you.

Comment: I suppose it is the *store* part @thoai-le needs an explanation about

Comment: I do not understand the functions and how to use Store will help what in the above.

Comment: Pealse check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395265/how-does-one-use-the-store-parameter-of-function-fields] i think it's what you looking for @ThoaiLe

Comment: Oh I am so happy. Thanks you very much

Comment: Pease check the answer as correct to help more people , you welcome @ThoaiLe

Comment: Sorry, I do not know check in where to check the answer as correct. Please, you can help me, so this question may help more people like me. Thanks you.

Comment: Please check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work @ThoaiLe